# Where should I post a question related to AWS/EC2?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question related to Amazon services ([AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services)/[EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud)) and databases. Basically here is my question (could add more details once asked on the right place):

> We are an online shop. We have a couple of self managed servers, production and development, with some databases on a MS SQL Server 2008R2 express instance. Also, we have another database hosted on the Amazon RDS service. Right now I've been asked to investigate the option of migrating all the production/development databases to Amazon AWS. Also check the viability of using EC2. Sorry if I'm miss using some terms, I'm just learning about all these services.
>
> Where should I start, doing some tests, creating a dummy database to test the different setups? Can I have some recommendation on tutorial/blog/FAQs where to find some useful information? Any recommendation will be welcomed as well as any previous experience doing this kind of migration to the AWS.

I see there are lot of questions about these subjects on different sites:

- SO: [amazon-ec2] **3,348** questions
  [aws] **955** questions
  aws+database: **71** questions
- serverfault: [amazon-ec2] **2411** questions
  [aws] **1512** questions
  aws+database: **3374** questions
- dba: [amazon-ec2] **45** questions
  [aws] **36** questions
  aws+database:  **0** questions

The DBA site has not much about the subject. But my question is more a DBA tasks related question. I'm thinking on either asking on Server Fault as it seems to hold the greater number of questions about the subject or replicating the question on the three sites. The second option seems to me not the correct one. But I'm afraid asking only on one of the sites and not only not having the needed answer, but not having an answer at all.

Comment: It depends (as usual)...what is your question?

Comment: I see your update, but I still don't see a question, really.

Comment: @Mat, updated again, hope is ok now, nevertheless I already have the answer I need.

Comment: Asking for recommendations & lists of links and plain old accounts of "experiences" doesn't usually make good SO questions. If you're looking for discussions, you're in the wrong place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also we have another database hosted on the Amazon RDS service. Right now I've been asked to investigate the option of migrating all the production/devolpment databases to Amazon AWS. Also check the viability of using EC2.

Based on that, I think DBA is the best fit.

Please do *not* replicate the question on all three sites.  Read the FAQ and some related questions each site to find the one where you think your question will be the best fit.  If the community on that site closes your question, then you can request that it be migrated to another site.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I was sure that to replicate the question was indeed not the right path. Will ask on DBA site and if I get no answer or none completly clear will ask to be migrated to ServerFault or SO.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (not mentioned in your shortlist ...) might be [DevOps.SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) (disclosure: I'm a mod over there ...), which currently has [115 questions tagged with amazon-ec2](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2?tab=Newest), and with tag info including this:

> For questions about using Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud in DevOps, including deploying, monitoring and scaling applications in EC2.

Note: DevOps.SE exists since 1Q2017 ...

Comment: question is from late 2017, that site may even not existed at that point

Comment: @Yaroslav check my updated answer (the note I added) ... so late 2017 it did exist ... however IMO your question is from 2012 ...

Comment: that's what I meant to say, 2012...confused Dec17 with the year